# How to approximate Graham's number using $10$ and some notation of large numbers.

Tags: recreational-mathematics, big-numbers

Graham's number in Expansion notation approximately equals
$3\{\{1\}\}65$ (this is based on $3$).

(This notation is explained in https://googology.fandom.com/wiki/Expansion).

I want approximation to Graham's number based on $10$ and expansion notation or up arrow notation.

(Arrow notation is explained in https://googology.fandom.com/wiki/Arrow_notation?so=search).

Comment: It makes not much difference to replace the $3$ by $10$.

Comment: @Peter Do you mean that $10\{\{1\}\}65$ will be valid approximation?

Comment: I am not very firm with this notation (usually Graham's number is defined by iterated Knuth-uparrows) , but if I understood it right , the first entry does not have a great impact , so I guess this number should not be vastly larger (in googology sense , of course). If it is similar to Bower arrays , the first entry is usually virtually irrelevant.

Comment: @Peter: I have become fascinated by large numbers. I am delving into googology, and I am curious to know if many of the questions surrounding large numbers will be resolved in the next 100 years, especially given the anticipated advancements in computing. In particular, I am keenly interested in the first digit of Graham's number.

Comment: @Peter: my start was because of you, when you mentioned TREE(3) and Graham's number few months ago, and recently I am studying the numbers in this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5hfkzo_ojGE

Comment: 1. It is unfortunately absolutely hopeless to determine the FIRST digits of Graham's number. 2. TREE(3) is a completely different league , unimaginably larger than Graham's number. 3. The most striking recent breakthrough was the discovery of a $6$-state busy beaver candidate writing about $10\uparrow \uparrow 15$ ones , the old record was just in the astrnomonical level.

Comment: Saibians site of the large numbers might be a good start , [here](https://sites.google.com/site/largenumbers/) is the link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150013/discussion-between-peter-and-mahmoud-albahar).